# A selection with the lowest id

Tags: sql

This is my thought...

I'm making a selection from a database and one of the columns is `oe.prodplan_id`. This one contains an number that referes to another table. Many of the selected rows contains the same number in `oe.prodplan_id` so i just want all the rows that contains the lowest value. For exampel all rows where `oe.prodplan_id = 1`.
The thing is that i dont now the lowest value, so from the selected rows i only want thoses with lowest number..
Maybe my explanation is bad, but so is my english :)

This is my sql question if it helps:

```
SELECT 
    oe.id AS oeID, oh.ordernumber, oe.order_line, oe.prod_week, 
    oe.prodplan_id, oe.door_type, oe.amount AS amountOfDoors, oe.inner_color, 
    oe.outer_color, oe.prod_week, a.name, a.description, i.amount AS iAmount, 
    md.status AS mdStatus, i.width, i.length, c.color_name AS innerColor, 
    c2.color_name AS outerColor, pp.status, oe.pos, d.name, md.id AS mdid 
FROM pd_mounting_details AS md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_eco AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_inventory AS i ON md.id = i.pp_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_head AS oh ON oe.order_head = oh.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_colors AS c ON oe.inner_color = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_colors AS c2 ON oe.outer_color = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_doors as d ON oe.door=d.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_production_plan AS pp ON oe.prodplan_id = pp.id 
WHERE 
     (a.production_group = 4) 
     AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)) 
     AND (pp.status = 4) 
     AND md.status = 4
     AND (startTime = '' OR startTime IS NULL) 
     AND (stopTime = '' OR stopTime IS NULL)
ORDER BY oe.pos
```

Best regards

Comment: On top of that, I'd like to know **WHICH** id?  Please post the column names of your tables.

Comment: @JNK: I'm lazy, and I'm a programmer - and those things crop up over and over and over again.... so take a guess! :-)

Comment: @Evil - the quality of  your question is extremely low, so it was closed.  You can edit it to improve it and have it reopened.

Comment: @JNK ok, thank you. I really haven't get tha hang of how this forum works.. I try to fix the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    oe.id AS oeID, oh.ordernumber, oe.order_line, oe.prod_week, 
    oe.prodplan_id, oe.door_type, oe.amount AS amountOfDoors, oe.inner_color, 
    oe.outer_color, oe.prod_week, a.name, a.description, i.amount AS iAmount, 
    md.status AS mdStatus, i.width, i.length, c.color_name AS innerColor, 
    c2.color_name AS outerColor, pp.status, oe.pos, d.name, md.id AS mdid 
FROM pd_mounting_details AS md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_eco AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_inventory AS i ON md.id = i.pp_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_head AS oh ON oe.order_head = oh.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_colors AS c ON oe.inner_color = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_colors AS c2 ON oe.outer_color = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_doors as d ON oe.door=d.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_production_plan AS pp ON oe.prodplan_id = pp.id 
WHERE 
     (a.production_group = 4) 
     AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)) 
     AND (pp.status = 4) 
     AND md.status = 4
     AND (startTime = '' OR startTime IS NULL) 
     AND (stopTime = '' OR stopTime IS NULL)

     --ADDED
     AND oe.prodplan_id = (SELECT MIN(prodplan_id) FROM pd_order_eco)

ORDER BY oe.pos
```

Comment: Actually i want all rows containing the lowest id, in the above exampel: oe.prodplan_id ?

Comment: @Evilaid: I am updating my answer. Also, your question has been closed, please see the comments and edit to provide the info asked for so more people can answer.

Comment: @Evilaid: I have updated my answer. Try it out and let me know if this works or NOT. Cheers.

Comment: It works just fine! Big thank you. Just how i wanted it.. And also, thanks for telling me what i did wrong with the question and why it got closed... I really dont understand what JNK means with the first comment saying "do you have that and the comment you post about accepting answers saved as macros" Anyhow: Thank you!

Comment: @Evilaid: Good, you are welcome. That first comment was directed towards someone else @ Marc_s, so maybe it was a bit confusing. Don't forget to accept my answer if it worked for you, and (I am not sure how to reopen this question, otherwise I would). Anyways, welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1):

You use a MIN() function.  Because that is an 'aggregate' function, you have to include the other fields in a GROUP BY clause.
For example:

```
SELECT
   MIN(prodplan.id),
   oh.ordernumber
FROM
   ...
WHERE
   ...
GROUP BY
   oh.ordernumber
```

Raw result set (based on all of your table joins, filters, etc.):

```
prodplan.id | oh.ordernumber | funny_word
1           | 1              | cow
2           | 1              | cow
3           | 1              | tree
```

Aggregated result set (Using MIN on prodplan.id)

```
1           | 1              | cow
3           | 1              | tree
```

It filtered out this record (because everything besides prodplan.id was the same, and the prodplan.id for the record it kept was the minimum number of the two)

```
2           | 1              | cow
```

Comment: so do i get all fields containing the lowest id of "oe.prodplan_id"?

Comment: I'll put an example up -- just a sec

Comment: Thank You.I used  VoodooChild exampel but i also used yours..